# jquery click not working - add/delete fields dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
```

and

```
$('#add').click(function(e){}
```

works

However, when I had

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <button type="button" id="remove" class="removeBtn">Delete</button>
```

and did this:

```
$('#remove').click(function(e){}
```

it didn't work.

I'm testing both with alert() to see if gets to the function.
The first button adds fields dynamically and works fine while the second button/s is the delete for that particular added field.
What seems to be the problem here? o.O

Comment: Instead of leaving function(e){} blank actually put in all your code so we can see what you're actually working with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you add several elements with your `add` button you'll end up having several elements with the same `#remove` id, which shouldn't happen.
Second, use event delegation to add click binding to dynamically generated elements.

```
$("#myUl").on("click", ".removeBtn", function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As the element is not present at the time of DOM load , the click event is not binded to it

```
$('#remove').click(function(e){}
```

change this to

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){}
```

you cannot use `id` for delete button .`id` is only for unique elements. here you need delete button for every `li`. So use `.remove` instead of `#remove`.(change id to class)

Comment: There is no reason for OP to switch to `.on()`.

Comment: @RahulDesai It is needed because the elements are dynamically added

Comment: @Bhadra The onclick works. Thanks. But I have to go with the other answer since it solves two of my problems : the click and the delete of dynamically added fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation method](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added jquery code.

Example:

```
 // attach a directly bound event
    $( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });

    // attach a delegated event
    $( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#remove').click(function(e){})

   please try this below instead of above

     $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){})

        or 

        // depreciated in jquery 1.7 and 1.9 pelase in jquery below 1.7
        $('body .remove').live('click',function(e){})
```